# Lock & Un lock of a table row in mysql (Inno Db)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

If one user reading/writing to a particular table row.

At the same time , if other user comes to read/write of that particular row . then he won't able to do that process.

Once the first user release that row, then only second user can access it.

How can i implement it in mysql?

I can use Lock & Unlock Table, but it will explicitly lock the entire table

Is there any another solution, so that row wise locking is possible?

Comment: set mysql's engine to `innodb`. It provides row level locking.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thanks for the comment.So you saying that if we use innodb, then row level locking is happening internally,and we don't need to implement it anything?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar  are you  sure?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines

Answer (score 1):

MySQL MyISAM supports `table-level locking`. Change to `InnoDB`  engine for `row-level locking`

The locking type is implied by the database itself.You need not do anything to force row level locking or table level locking.

> MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables to support simultaneous
>   write access by multiple sessions, making them suitable for
>   multi-user, highly concurrent, and OLTP applications. MySQL uses
>   table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables, allowing
>   only one session to update those tables at a time, making them more
>   suitable for read-only, read-mostly, or single-user applications.

It's called [Internal Locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html) where locking performed within the MySQL server

More about **[how to lock a row for read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Currently iam using inno Db.
So you saying that if we use innodb, then row level locking is happening internally,and we don't need to implement it anything?

Comment: Ok,my situation is, while one user reads a row, then other user can't able to read that record.Is it possible for innodb in automatically?

I read the row level locking is happening  during write or delete of a record